# When is 'onClosed' triggered for Chrome notifications?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This seems like a really silly question, but I can't seem to exactly understand how / when 'onClose' is triggered for some notifications I create.

Here is some relevant code:

```
// USAGE:   on notification close, remove stored album URL from local storage
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function (notificationID, byUser) {
    console.log("trying to remove something...");

    if (byUser) {
        console.log(`removing ${notificationID} by user`);
        chrome.storage.local.remove(notificationID);
    }
});
```

Here are some interesting cases I noticed:

For reference: (1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fwK0.png (2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzABH.png

1a) onClose is **not triggered** after I click the top-right 'X' that appears hovering my mouse near that area. However, the notification is "cleared" from the notifications list.

1b) onClose is **not triggered** after I select "Clear all notifications" near the bottom of the notifications list, despite all the notifications disappearing from the list right after.

2) onClose **is triggered occasionally by the system** upon creating notifications. In the screenshot, I am parsing through a list of artist and their albums. A notification for the album is created if the album details passes some criterion.

In addition, I can't seem to find any cases where the notification is detected as being closed by the user (i.e. byUser == true).

Thanks in advance for any hints / tips / comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onClosed` event is fired when you close the notification from here

[image]

If you try to clear them from the Windows Notification Center after they have disappeared, the `onClosed` event won't be triggered.
If you do not close them, then the `onClosed` event will be fired by the system.

I created three notifications and closed them using their dismiss button (->).

[image]

Comment: Ah, got it! I had "Focus Assist" on and forgot that all my non-alarm notifications will just show up on the Windows Notification Center instead. > <|||